# perl - package name: Can I use path from root?

Tags: perl, module, path

I am reading documentation about `use`. It is the same as

```
BEGIN{ require Namespace::NameOfModule; }
```

And the perl interpreter loads the module and translate the double colon `::` to system path's separator (UNIX `/` and WINDOWS `\\`, if I remember correctly). I just wondered, If I am able to load module from root. Because in that case, for example module `DateTime.pm` in dir `/home/nickname/dir`. It would be (according to double colons rule) `::home::nickname::dir`, which is wrong (like it should even look like terrible package path). So how - if even - is possible to load a module from root dir? And Does the path starts from current dir by default? (That is from dir where is the perl script located in), or only from `@INC` dirs?

Comment: Re "*translate the double colon `::` to system path's separator (UNIX `/` and WINDOWS `\\ `, if I remember correctly)*", No, `/` on all systems. `/` is a perfectly valid path separator in Windows.

Comment: `use lib '/'` would allow you to have modules in the root dir

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, They actually asked to load modules in a subdir of their home dir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module namespace is relative to `@INC` directories only. These are by default set up according to where Perl was installed, with privlib (core modules installed with Perl), sitelib (modules installed by a CPAN client), and vendorlib (modules installed by a vendor package manager), and architecture-specific versions of each of these. Additional `@INC` directories may be added by [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib), and before Perl 5.26 `@INC` also included `.` (the current working directory), but this was a bad idea.

When you invoke `use` or `require` on a bareword package name, it does the translation you described (convert `::` to path separator and append `.pm`), and then appends it to each directory in `@INC` until it finds a file. (It also checks for `.pmc` but this is rarely relevant.) The package statement inside the file is expected to match the module path used to look it up for the import component of `use`.

You can modify `@INC` manually, but it is best to do it with one of the following mechanisms, so that architecture-specific and version-specific subdirectories will be respected if present.

- [lib](https://perldoc.pl/lib) - `use lib '/path/to/lib';`
- [-I](https://perldoc.pl/perlrun#-Idirectory) - `perl -I/path/to/lib ...`
- [PERL5LIB](https://perldoc.pl/perlrun#PERL5LIB) - `env PERL5LIB=/path/to/lib perl ...`

These options should only be used to insert absolute paths into `@INC`, since relative paths will have the same vulnerability as `.` used to, in that they may mean something different when the current directory is changed. To add a path relative to the script wherever it may be, [lib::relative](https://metacpan.org/pod/lib::relative) can be installed to simplify the process, or its documentation describes equivalent functionality using core modules.

```
use lib::relative '../lib';
```

Once you have added your custom location(s) to `@INC`, that directory will be searched first for any further `use` calls.

```
use Foo::Bar; # now checks /path/to/lib/Foo/Bar.pm first
# which should contain package Foo::Bar
```

Comment: The module `lib::relative` is similar to `FindBin` (for my purpose)? Seems, it is, but maybe implementation is different.

Comment: @Herdsman It can be used to achieve a similar task, but FindBin has (currently) unfixable bugs on old Perls and relies on the mutable `$0` program name rather than current source filename, so I do not recommend it outside of that specific use case. I also recently released [Path::This](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::This) to replace other uses of FindBin.

Comment: Ok, I will look at that module as well

Comment: But still don't get it. If i have my module in current dir and `use FindBin qw[$RealBin];use lib "$RealBin";`, And try to use a sub from that module, then `Can't locate object method ...`, How it is possible, when I `use` the `$RealBin`?

Comment: Correction, I have not `use` the module as well. But now it works. It is however misleading, when you `use` to include dir with module, and then `use` for the module (concrete file) also. There should be another functionality to distinct them.

Comment: @Herdsman These are in fact two very distinct tasks. The first is adding the directory as a location to look for modules, then you have to use modules from that location which would specify what file path within that location to load (this could happen more than once).

Comment: @Herdsman The distinction is important, because the path added to `@INC` is not relevant to the module name, but the path appended to each `@INC` dir to look for a module will match the module name.

Comment: @Grinzz, but the `use` func in perldoc, is documented only the case of particular module (that is, particular file path), and not mentioned about including dirs. Why it is not there too?

Comment: @Herdsman This functionality is part of the [require](https://perldoc.pl/functions/require) component so it's documented there.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you could load the module like that, you'd have numerous other problems.

- The module's `package` directive would have to be `package ::home::nickname::dir::SomeModule;` for `import` to be found.
- You'd have to use `::home::nickname::dir::SomeModule->some_method` to call a static method.
- You'd have to use `::home::nickname::dir::SomeModule::some_sub` to call a sub.

That's obviously the wrong approach.

For modules installed in a position relative to a script, use the following in the script to tell `perl` where to look:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$RealBin/../lib";  # Or whatever.
```

For modules installed for any script to use, use the following environment variable:

```
export PERL5LIB="$HOME/dir"  # Or whatever.
```

Comment: If i try `use ::home::nickname::dir::DateTime`, then `Bareword in require must not start with a double-colon`. But I will try to `use` FindBin

Comment: Fixed. . . . . .